# need some help renewing api-server certs running on 1.18

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

My prod AKS cluster is running on 1.18 and i'm not able to run any kubectl command because the api-cert is expired a day ago.

cluster is throwing the error below:

`x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2022-12-05T12:30:28+05:30 is`

I do see there are few blogs referring to rotate certs using the below command.
az aks rotate-certs -g $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME -n $CLUSTER_NAME

As this is a cluster running on older k8 version, i'm wondering if the above step works.
can this be run during working hours?
running this command will have any impact on the workloads?

any help is greatly appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to renew the API server certificate in my environment and got the below results***

> Kubernetes uses certificates for authentication with many of components
> If we have RABC enabled for the cluster then its enabled with the auto rotation for certificate

For checking the expiry date for the certificate

```
kubectl config view --raw -o jsonpath="{.users[?(@.name == 'clusterUser_rg_cluster_name')].user.client-certificate-data}" | base64 -d | openssl x509 -text | grep -A2 Validity
```

[image]

To check the expiry date of certificate use the below command

```
az vm run-command invoke -g Alldemorg -n linuxvmaks --command-id RunShellScript --query 'value[0].message' -otsv --scripts "openssl x509 -in /etc/kubernetes/certs/apiserver.crt -noout -enddate"
```

[image]

To upgrade the cluster use the below command

```
az aks upgrade -g rg_name -n cluster_name
```

To sign into the cluster

```
az aks get-credentials -g rg-name -n cluster-name
```

[image]

To rotate all the certificates

```
az aks rotate-certs -g rg-name -n cluster-name
```

[image]

To verify the old certificates are valid or not by using below command

```
kubectl get pods
```

[image]

By using above command I am not able to access the **`kubectl`** commands
To enable the `kubectl` commands use the below command

[image]

When I check the `kubectl` command I am able to access

```
kubectl get nodes
```

[image]